# Azure SQL: The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, dreamspark

I have an Azure ASP.NET web application with an Azure SQL Database for authentication. I copied the connection string to my web.config, and it works on my local machine if I debug.

But if I publish it to Azure and open the site from web, when I try to use the DB (for example I try to login), I get the following error:

> The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type.

If I try to connect to the DB via Visual Studio Server Explorer, when I try to login to the server I get the same error.

My Azure subscription is a DreamSpark subscription, so it's not a pay-as-you go, but a totally free one (for students). I've searched for this error message and some results were associated with different subscription types (that's why I guess that my problem is in connection with the DreamSpark subscription type) but honestly I couldn't figure out any possible solution.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft Azure for DreamSpark subscription, you will initially only be able to

> access Azure services that are available with a **free tier** of service
>   use.

Your account will start with a zero dollar Spending Limit, which means that you will only be able to consume Azure services within the free tier of the service offer.

You can choose to upgrade to Azure Free Trial, if you have not already created an Azure Free Trial and consume Azure services beyond the free tier.

If you have already created an Azure Free Trial then you have the option to upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription.

For more details, see:

[DreamSpark Azure Offer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, my DB is in Free tier (5 DTUs, max 32 MB). But in free tier shouldn't I be able to access my DB via internet? Or if I should, how can I do it?